# Chalk outline using vertex component with p5js

Tags: p5.js

I'm trying to draw a chalk outline on the body using vertex component of p5js. Below is an image showing an attempt to draw an outline on the image in question, and my current code. I am new to coding. Please use basic terms.

[image]

```
var img;

function preload()
{
    img = loadImage('scene.png');
}

function setup()
{
    createCanvas(img.width,img.height);
}

function draw()
{

    image(img,0,0);
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    strokeWeight(3);
    noFill();

    // write the code to draw around the Judge's body below

    beginShape();
    
    vertex(900,800)
    vertex(150,100)
    vertex(400,600)
    vertex(250,400)
    vertex(300,200)
    vertex(75,90)
    
    endShape();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you basically have to draw the outline manually with a bunch of points, just the way you've done so far (there are ways to do it automatically, but the only ones I know of require some pretty advanced techniques). Here's some code that might help you figure out where to draw the points:

```
let vertexList = [];
let img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("scene.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(img.width, img.height);
}

function draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0);
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  strokeWeight(3);
  noFill();
  
  //draw the current outline
  
  beginShape();
  for (let vert of vertexList) {
    vertex(vert.x, vert.y);
  }
  endShape();
}

function mousePressed() {
  vertexList.push(createVector(mouseX, mouseY));
}

function keyPressed() {
  print('beginShape();');
  for (let vert of vertexList) {
    print('vertex(' + str(vert.x) + ', ' + str(vert.y) + ');');
  }
  print('endShape();');
}
```

Instructions: click at all the points you want to draw, then press any key. The desired code will print to the console, so just copy that and paste it into your code (replace your current `beginShape();...endShape();`).

There is usually a keyboard shortcut to adjust indentation if that bothers you. In the web editor it's Ctrl + Shift + f.